# SendKeys ALT + SPACE

Tags: c#

Okay so I've done my research and I know it's not possible to send a spacebar with `SendKeys()`, and the solution is to use `SendKeys(" ")`.

However, what I'm trying to do is send <kbd>ALT + SPACEBAR</kbd> to a command window (this combination opens the menu and i'm trying to copy out text using only keystrokes)

I've tried `SendKeys.SendWait("%( )")`; but that's just sending a space as text. I'm really stuck here because I need the actual spacebar to be pressed while holding ALT for my shortcut to work.

Comment: Have you tried AutoIt: http://tonylitchfield.com/getting-started/5-using-autoit-within-c-and-visual-studio-2010.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [following](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx) syntax

```
SendKeys.Send("% ");
```

Where `%` means ALT

Comment: Or maybe Send("%{SPACE}");

Comment: SendKeys.Send("% "); works fine, the problem is definitely now with your implementation.

Answer (score -1):

In order to send Alt+Space, the following code will work:

```
Application.SendKeys "%{ }"
```

Comment: It will be more helpful if you explain a little about your solution

Comment: Doesn't work, causes: System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword " " is not valid.'